# Send data from page to page in Next JS - App Route - Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, app-router

Please help, I need to get data from an array of a page, then display it on another page.
I'm, using NextJs, with Typescript, AppRoute
Here's my code:

app/page.tsx:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'

const listMember = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name1",
    age: 20,
  },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "name2",
    age: 18,
  },
    {
    id: 3,
    name: "name3",
    age: 2,
  }
]

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <ul className="px-5">
        {listMember.map(member =>
          <li>
            <Link
              href={{
                pathname: "/Detail",
                query: member.name
              }}>{member.name}</Link>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

app/Detail/page.tsx

```
import HomePage from "../page";

export default function Detail() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1> 
                This is detail page of {HomePage.listMember.name}
            </h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

I have tried to use route but not working

Comment: I'm guessing that your array is just mocking data that would come from an API. If you want it on another page, just fetch it from there.
It looks like you try to import the HomePage into the Detail page. This will not work, because those functions are not components, but routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the list from your main page

```
export const listMember = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name1",
    age: 20,
  },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "name2",
    age: 18,
  },
    {
    id: 3,
    name: "name3",
    age: 2,
  }
]
```

and then access the query param from the detail page and find the param like this:

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import HomePage,{listMember} from "../page";

export default function Detail() {
const searchParams = useSearchParams()
const name = searchParams.get('name')


  const member = listMember.find(member => member.name === name);

    return (
        <>
            <h1> 
                This is detail page of {member?.name}
            </h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: this seem almost work for me, but 'next/router' is now can no more used, i can not use 'router.query'. Can you suggest another solution ?

Comment: for query params you can try 
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params

Comment: I've edited the example using this, give it a try @MinhDat

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
export const listMember = [...
...
```

```
import {listMember } from "../page";

export default function Detail() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1> 
                This is detail page of {listMember.name}
            </h1>
        </>
    )
}
```